# Is Gen an instance of Functor?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor

I am learning about functors in Haskell, and I would like to know whether QuickCheck's [`Gen`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Gen) is an instance of `Functor`? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Note that since recent versions of GHCi you can get a list of instances for any type T by entering `:info T`.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's low effort.

Comment: In the future, I recommend using [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) to do research for this kind of question.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: @DanielWagner You have the perspective of an experienced Haskeller (and an experienced programmer). For someone less experienced it's not always easy to know how to understand the documentation or even where to find it. Besides, there are plenty of questions on Stack Overflow whose answer can be found in the docs; the Q&A format is a good opportunity to explain and expand on the documentation (as Willem has done in his answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**. This is described in the [documentation for **`Gen`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#t:Gen): under the *instances* section, it shows `Functor Gen`.

It is [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.13.2/docs/src/Test.QuickCheck.Gen.html#line-54):

> ```
> instance Functor Gen where
>   fmap f (MkGen h) =
>     MkGen (\r n -> f (h r n))
> ```

`MkGen` is the data constructor of `Gen`. It contains a function of type `QCGen -> Int -> a`. What we thus basically do is create a function `\r n -> f (h r n)` that thus will "post-process" the result of `h r n`.